# Integrating Jsplumb with vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, jsplumb

I am trying to do a simple example of connecting two div using jsplumb. So I integrated jsplumb with Vuejs and tried one example. I did npm install jsplumb. Then used like this:

```
<div>
    <div id="diagramContainer">
        <div id="item_left" class="item"></div>
        <div id="item_right" class="item" style="margin-left:50px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>   
<script>
import jsplumb from 'jsplumb'
        jsPlumb.ready(function() {
            jsPlumb.connect({
                source:"item_left",
                target:"item_right",
                endpoint:"Rectangle"
            })
        })
</script> 
<style>
        #diagramContainer {
            padding: 20px;
            width:80%; height: 200px;
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }

        .item {
            height:80px; width: 80px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            float: left;
        }
</style>
```

but now I’m getting an error like this:

```
20:2-16 "export 'default' (imported as '__vue_script__') was not found in '!!babel-loader!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0&bustCache!./jsplumb.vue'
```

I don’t know how to proceed further. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change your import to:

```
import jsplumb from 'jsPlumb'
```

and then use it as follow:

```
jsplumb.jsPlumb.ready(...)
```